# How to get average speed using time and distance travelled

Tags: java

This code does work but am not sure if am getting the correct answers from it have I used the wrong formula or something? I placed the forum at the end of the code in a double-line comment. Please don't tell me to add fail safes or any of that I want to keep it less confusing.

```
  public class ICS3URightOnJavaAssignment2c
  {
      public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
      {
          BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

          String d; //creates a string variable to get distance (travelled) from user
          double distance = 0.0; //double distance
          System.out.print("Enter distance travelled(KM): ");  //gets distance travelled from user
          d = buffer.readLine(); //reads a line from the console
          distance = Double.parseDouble(d);//gets the double value from string variable d
          System.out.println("Distance Travelled: " + d); //states string variable d

          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

          String t; //creates a string variable to get time (travelled) from user
          double time = 0.0; //double time
          System.out.print("Enter time travelled(Minutes): "); //gets time travelled from user
          t = buffer.readLine(); //reads a line from the console
          time = Double.parseDouble(t);//gets the double value from string variable t
          System.out.println("Time Travelled: " + t); //states string variable t

          System.out.println("The average speed (KM/H) with a distance travelled of " + d + and time travelled of " + t + " is " + distance / time);

          /*speed (average) = distance divided by time*/      
      }
  }
```

Comment: Is there any reason for you to believe the output is wrong or do you just want us to check your code? If it's the latter, this is unfortunately not really appropriate for [so] ([so] is for helping you with problems you've found, not analysing code to find them). But yes, `distance / time` is how you would calculate the speed. Although `time` is in minutes, not hours, thus you need to multiply `time` / divide the result by 60.

Comment: You had a redundant pair of `{}` in your code, which I removed. And `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));` (the one on it's own line) doesn't do anything, it should be removed. And I indented your code to make it more readable.

Comment: There's also a missing " sign in the last println.